# How change class of a div without id?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

**EDIT**
Provided more HTML code and rephrased problem statement

**I have the following code to start with which I can't change**

```
<div class="text-component mode-sub-section" tabindex="0" role="link">
 <h4 class="text-heading" role="heading">Text here</h4>
 <p class="text-body mode-sub-section display-collapsed">some long text    
 here</p>
 <a class="see-more-text" aria-label="Show more About">Show less</a>
</div>
```

**I know**

```
text-body mode-sub-section display-collapsed
```

causes the text on the page to be wrapped and users need to click on "Show more" to get the full text.

**What I want** is that the page shows (on page load!) the unwrapped, full text. I want to achieve this by a JS Greasemonkey-Script.

**What I have is this Greasemonkey script. This is all the code** (I can change this part)

```
(function() {
'use strict';
  setTimeout(function (){
    let div_list = document.querySelectorAll(".display-collapsed");
      for (let i = 0; i < div_list.length; i++) {
      let ele = div_list[i];
      ele.classList.remove("display-collapsed");
      ele.classList.add("display-full");
      }
    }, 5000, );
})();
```

**Behaviour observed:** On page load, the "some long text here" text loads in *abridged* form and users need to click "show more" to see the full text.
The console logs the following for the "post" variable:

```
post: NodeList [ p.text-body.mode-sub-section.display-full ]
```

**Behaviour desired:** On page load, the "some long text here" text loads in the *unabridged* form.

Comment: You have: `<p>class="text-body mode-sub-section display-collapsed">`? Do you mean: `<p class="text-body mode-sub-section display-collapsed">`?

Comment: You also indicate that you are getting an error, but what exact error do you get and what line do you get it on?

Comment: Please add all the relevant code (HTML and CSS) so that we can replicate your issue and provide a working result.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottMarcus Re: 1: Yes, I meant the latter. Corrected this now. Re: 2: I rephrased this in the question above. Actually, I don't get an error in the console. My code just doesn't result in the described desired behaviour. Re: 3: I added more HTML, but am unsure where to get the CSS from.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alternative way is this...

```
$('.mode-sub-section').toggleClass('your_default_class the_class_your_want_to_replace');
```

Comment: This logs the following and the page still loads with the collapsed text which is what I don't intend:`Object { 0: div.text-component.mode-sub-section.text-body.mode-sub-section.display-full 1: div.text-component.mode-sub-section.type-attached.text-body.mode-sub-section.display-full 2: div#a2s-see-all-reviews.text-component.mode-sub-section.type-navigation.text-body.mode-sub-section.display-full length: 3, prevObject: {…}, context: HTMLDocument https://someurl.de/spa/index.html#skills/dp/B07KW4HR8Y/?ref=skill_dsk_stpcs__1, selector: "div.text-component.mode-sub-section" `